# Codeigniter + Boostrap : split tab-content in multiple files

Tags: php, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

first of all I'm a newbie in web development so...
I don't know if there is a way to do the following (neither if it's a best practice).

I have a CodeIgniter + Angularjs application where there is a view contains a Bootstrap tab (which is also a angular app):

```
[view_general_params.php]

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="HouseController">
    <div class="container">

      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
        <li class="active"><a href="#general" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#panel_params"  data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="#house_params" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
        <li><a href="#statistics" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
      </ul>

      <div class="tab-content">

      </div>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now, since each tab must contains a lot of controls (Textboxes etc..) I'm asking myself if there is a way to split it in different files loaded by the controller in this way:

```
 public function details($house_id)
 {
      $user = $this->session->userdata('user');

      if (is_null($user)) {
           $this->session->sess_destroy();
           redirect('login/index');
      }
      else {
           $data = $this->create_data_array($user);
           $data['house'] = $this->houses_model->get_house($house_id);
           $data['title'] = "House details";

           $this->load->view('head_navbar', $data);
           $this->load->view('house_details_view', $data);
           $this->load->view('view_general_params', $data);
           $this->load->view('view_house_params', $data);
           $this->load->view('view_panel_params', $data);
           $this->load->view('view_statistics', $data);
     }
 }
```

where each others views contain data for a single tab-page:

```
[view_general_params.php]

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="general">
          general controls...
        </div>
      </div> 
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. In Codeigniter you can use a view as a template. Take these steps:

1. create a folder in your `views` directory, call it "Templates".
   `application\views\templates\`
2. create each template the way you want and place it inside the templates folder:
   `application\views\templates\head_navbar.php`

   `application\views\templates\house_details_view.php`

   `application\views\templates\view_general_params.php`
3. In your controller, you want to call these templates with a third paramater set to `TRUE`, then passing this to as an array value. This array will then be sent to your main view, like this:

   ```
   public function details($house_id) {
       $user = $this->session->userdata('user');

       if (is_null($user)) {
          $this->session->sess_destroy();
          redirect('login/index');
       } else {
          $data = $this->create_data_array($user);
          $data['house'] = $this->houses_model->get_house($house_id);
          $data['title'] = "House details";

          $data_to_final_view = array(
             "view1" => $this->load->view('head_navbar', $data, TRUE),
             "view2" => $this->load->view('house_details_view', $data, TRUE),
             "view3" => $this->load->view('view_house_params', $data, TRUE),
             "view4" => $this->load->view('view_panel_params', $data, TRUE),
             "view5" => $this->load->view('view_statistics', $data, TRUE)
          );

          $this->load->view('view_general_params', $data_to_final_view);
       }
   }
   ```
4. Now, in your `view_general_params` view, you can place the template's content anywhere you want:

   ```
   <div class="container">
       <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
           <li class="active"><a href="#general" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
           <li><a href="#panel_params"  data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
           <li><a href="#house_params" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
           <li><a href="#statistics" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
       </ul>

       <div class="tab-content1">
           <?= $view1 ?>
       </div>
       <div class="tab-content2">
           <?= $view2 ?>
       </div>
        ... etc..
   </div>
   ```